# WEKA, how to set several decision rules in one node of random tree?

Tags: java, weka

how to set several decision rules in one node of random tree ?

for example:

simple node has :
petallength < 2.45 : Iris-setosa (50/0)

I want to change this for :
petallength < 2.45, petalwidth < 1.75, ... : Iris-setosa (50/0)
...

I found some code in file Random Tree:

This function prints the tree:

```
protected String toString(int level) {
    ...
    // this contain the name attribute for simple node
    m_Info.attribute(m_Attribute).name();
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you included a minimal working example as code to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This contradicts the fundamental working principal of Decision Trees. In each node, exactly one feature/variable is examined and the tree branches depending on the value of this feature.

To support my claim:

- > The algorithm creates a multiway tree, finding for each node (i.e. in a greedy manner) the categorical feature that will yield the largest information gain for categorical targets.

  [Source](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart)
- > Each interior node corresponds to one of the input variables

  [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning)